# Automate copying columns

Tags: excel, vba

I need a dynamic/smart macro that will copy columns D and E and insert them 2 columns over (i.e. they will be inserted as new columns H and I), then repeat the process until I reach the last column. For example, this is the static/dumb way:

```
Sub Copy_Test()

    Columns("D:E").Copy
    Columns("H").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    Columns("H:I").Copy
    Columns("L").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    Columns("L:M").Copy
    Columns("P").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    Columns("P:Q").Copy
    Columns("T").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

I know I would need some sort of FOR loop, I'm just really bad at writing those! BTW, Row 4 can be used to determine the last column in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I didn't fully understand the problem. Note that the offset of the columns and their overlap in the copying process makes the result look strange.

```vb
Sub Copy_Test()
    last_col = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column in row 4
    col = 4 'start column "D"
    Do While col < last_col
        Columns(col + 4).Resize(, 2).Insert   'prepare 2 new columns for further copy
        Columns(col).Resize(, 2).Copy Columns(col + 4).Resize(, 2) 'copy 2 adjacent columns from col column
        col = col + 4   'move to the next column
    Loop
End Sub
```